# Объединить метки "instagram" и "инстаграмм"

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Объединить:

- [instagram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) - 100 вопросов,
- [инстаграмм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc) - 2 вопроса.

Но, наверное, лучше вообще удалить метку [инстаграмм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc).

Comment: Удаление бессмысленно. Кто-нибудь снова создаст. Надо синонимизировать.